# Flutter 2.0.4 (stable): Null check operator used on a null value ERROR

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I recently migrated my app to Flutter 2.0 which contains Null safety. After successful migration, when I run the app, I get the following error

*The following _CastError was thrown building ContactListWidget(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery, _InheritedProviderScope], state: _ContactListWidgetState#9ca7f)*

The error mentions no line number where the error is getting thrown, the code is approximately 500 lines :/

How do I fix this issue? Is it related to Firebase queries/data?

**EDIT**

I was able to locate the erroneous line, and it seems like a problem with the usage of `?`  and `!`. Can anyone direct to a resource where it is easy to understand null safety? Thanks

Comment: Well, if you don't get a proper error and cannot catch it with a debugger, then the only option that's left is comment out the whole build function of ContactListWidget and put it back line by line and see at which point it fails.

Comment: Are you sure there is no stack trace printed to the console?  Can you get a stack trace if you surround the body of your `ContactListWidget.build` function with a `try`-`catch` and print it yourself?

Comment: yes, found the stack trace, silly doubt, though its a matter of ? and ! which is causing the problem

Comment: Yeah, too many peope add ? and ! to get Dart to SHUDDUP, and don't realize that they are making runtime promises for those.